# Results of past NCAA games

Tags: data-request, sports, historical

Are they any openly available lists of the scores of NCAA games in football or basketball?  The information exists in pieces on sites like [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Texas_Longhorns_football_team), and [Stanford Graph Base](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/sgb.html) has the entire 1990 NCAA division 1 football schedule in a nice format, but I wondering if there is a comprehensive list that would be easier to get then scraping [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_SEC_football_season#Regular_season) pages.

Comment: Not having much luck ('free' gets you 'free throws'); I found NCAA basketball tournaments, but not the regular season : http://www.databasesports.com/ .  Data's out there and atleast one site says they'll help with small data ... but don't want scraping and direct you to other companies for large dumps : http://www.sports-reference.com/data_use.shtml .  [Another site](http://www.teamrankings.com/) has a lot of stats, but they claim 'database rights' of the 'content' (likely won't hold up in court, but why bother?).  [Yet another](http://statsheet.com/) has a ToS that forbids 'copying data'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a git repo with the data I have collected from the past few seasons for the NCAA mens basketball division I. 
Check it out here: 
https://github.com/mgoldwasser/ncaa-basketball-historical-final-game-scores

Comment: I just added NCAA mens basketball data for the 2013-2014 season! Check it out

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this College Football Statistics & History site: http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb.

Comment: Thanks.  This does have a [terms of service](http://www.sports-reference.com/termsofuse.shtml) that forbids "harvest, or collect any part of the Site or Content without SRL's advance written consent"

Comment: @DavidNehme: Sorry, my bad! I've forgotten to check the ToS.